# Cómo deshabilitar opciones en una tabla?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Necesito deshabilitar las opciones que se están presentando de acuerdo a la opción que seleccione, los valores que se presentan se están tomando desde la base de datos.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li data-ng-repeat="itemStatus in result=status">
    <a href="" title="" data-ng-click="ChangeStatus(item.id,itemStatus.id,itemStatus.name)">
      {{itemStatus.name}}
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Lo que necesito es que una vez escogido uno de los tres estados los otros dos se deshabiliten. Esto con el fin de que no se vuelva a escoger otro estado que se encuentra en la tabla de la base.

**¿Como puedo deshabilitar las otras opciones?**

Comment: Cuando hablas de "deshabilitar", ¿a qué te refieres con exactitud? Pregunto porque estás trabajando con tags `a` y estos **no pueden** ser deshabilitados como los botones o cajas de texto. ¿Deseas agregar una clase que represente dicho estado?

Comment: Gracias. En este caso no sé si se pueda deshabilitar el botón que hace que la lista de opciones aparezca.

Comment: Inicialmente se cargan tres opciones, pero al escoger dos de ellas no debe ser posible visualizarlas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una solución simple es guardar en tu controlador una variable que almacene el estado seleccionado. Luego, por medio de `n-show` poner el condicional para que solo se muestre **si aún no ha sido seleccionado** un estado o si el estado seleccionado es el elemento actual dentro de la iteración.

**Ejemplo**

```js
const app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.statuses = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'waiting',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'running',
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'detached',
    }
  ];
  $scope.selStatus = '';
  $scope.selectStatus = function(id) {
    $scope.selStatus = id;
  };
}]);
```

```css
a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    <h3>Select status</h3>
    <ul>
      <li
        ng-show="selStatus === '' || status.id === selStatus"
        ng-repeat="status in statuses"
      >
        <a ng-click="selectStatus(status.id)">{{status.name}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Si, la solución fue mediante ng-show.

     <div class="btn-group" data-ng-show="item.status.name =='estado' ">.
Gracias.